# SQL Server sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities does not return any results but sp_depends stored procedure does

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to select the entities that a stored procedure depends on. When using

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('StoredProcName', 'OBJECT')
```

this returns no results.

If I use the stored procedure sp_depends

```
Exec sp_depends @objname = N'StoredProcName'
```

I get the results I am expecting.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also note that I am able to use sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities to get referencing stored procedures with no problem.

Comment: What about when you select from sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities instead?

Comment: sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities works fine.

Comment: Per books online, it states: `Returns an empty result set under any of the following conditions:
A system object is specified.
The specified entity does not exist in the current database.
The specified entity does not reference any entities.
An invalid parameter is passed.`  Can you clarify if any of the conditions are met?

Comment: Yes I have also read this. The stored procedure is not a system stored procedure and definitely references other stored procedures which are returned when calling sp_depends. I am only passing in the stored procedure name as parameter one and 'OBJECT' as parameter two, these parameters work when using sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities.

Comment: I know it's not an answer to your question, but I've once also had problem with this function, instead I started to use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` view.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with schema? Try passing schema qualified object name, e.g. `dbo.StoredProcName` or `schema.StoredProcName`.

Comment: @Endrju I tried passing in different object names qualifying the schema etc... but this didn't work. Still not sure why.
I am able to achieve what I need using:
    `SELECT name, type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT referenced_major_id FROM sys.sql_dependencies 
WHERE OBJECT_ID =  OBJECT_ID('StoredProcName'))`

Comment: Avoid `sys.sql_dependencies`, as it's deprecated; use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`.

Comment: Also don't need to join to `sys.objects`, just use `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)` and `OBJECT_NAME(major_id)`